# Extracting flash object from word doc through openxml using c#

Tags: c#, interop, ms-office

I want to extract a flash object from a word doc using OpenXml.I have done it other way round but it is not working as, if there are many flash objects then the processing time got hampered and henceforth i think openxml is more suitable>please someone help me in doing the same .I am coding in c#

Comment: Wow, you are really asking for a lot.

Comment: does the below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use this: [Standalone tool for extracting embedded Office Open XML objects from files](http://embeddedoleextractor.codeplex.com/)